# Customizing setUp in PHPUnit

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing, phpunit

I'm looking to run a bunch of tests with one object with different parameters in the setUp function.

How do I do this? I tried using the @dataProvider, but that doesn't work with setUp I quickly found out..

Here's what I'd like to do (using @dataProvider):

```
/*
* @dataProvider provider
*/
function setUp($namespace, $args) {
   $this->tag = new Tag($namespace, $args);
}

function provider() {
   return array(
      array('hello', array()),
      array('world', array())
   );
}

function testOne() {

}

function testTwo() {

}
```

**The result is that testOne() and testTwo() are run against an object with the namespace "hello" and an object with the namespace "world"**

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't have to assign the SUT to a member variable of the TestCase instance if it does not suit the test. Simply create new Tag instances in the provider and pass them to the test function instead

```
/**
 * Provides different test Tag instances
 */
function tagProvider() {
   return array(
      array( new Tag( 'hello', array() ) ),
      array( new Tag( 'world', array() ) )
   );
}

/*
* @dataProvider tagProvider
*/
function testOne( Tag $tag ) {
    $this->assertSomething( $tag );
}
```

If `testOne` alters the test in a way that `testTwo` depends on the changes, you can do:

```
/*
* @dataProvider tagProvider
*/
function testOne( Tag $tag ) {
    $this->assertSomething( $tag );
    return $tag;
}

/*
* @depends testOne
*/
function testTwo( Tag $tag ) {
    $this->assertSomething( $tag );
}
```

And then `testTwo` will use the returned `$tag` from `testOne`, along with any state changes made to it in `testOne`.

Comment: @Matt follow-up question, do i need to unset those Tag objects i created in tagProvider(), if so, shall i make them class variables and unset in teardown()?

Comment: Putting them inside class properties would just add a reference to those objects, that will have to be teared down afterwards.
As far as I know, in PHP, keeping those objects just in the data-provider will candidate them for garbage collection automatically, once no more methods use/refer those objects/references.
[With PHPUnit happens the same](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/7.3/fixtures.html#fixtures-more-setup-than-teardown).
`tearDown()` is mostly useful for unloading external resources (like database connections) that are not natively handled by the language (like object instances).